# Ideal Server Specs for Sharepoint Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, hardware

We are about a month to the deployment stage of our Sharepoint Server.
What would be an ideal specification (memory, HDD, etc.) for the Sharepoint Server that will serve about 130 employees.

We are using Sharepoint Server 2010 Standard and would be used only as an intranet site.
The 130 users would store files too.

P.S. I don't know why but the current sharepoint server, that is still under development, is utilizing 6G of memory.
The server has only sharepoint and SQL installed and sharepoint does not even have any contents/documents uploaded. It is empty and no users are connected to it except me.
Could someone tell me what troubleshooting steps I can take?
Thanks

Comment: To answer this, many more details are necessary (how many Service Applications will be in use, etc), but 130 users would be considered to be a very low user count (assuming you mean 130 total users and not 130 concurrent users) and the small sharepoint farm in the technet documentation would most likely be more than sufficient for this small amount of users.

Have you read the capacity planning sections for SharePoint 2010 on Technet? 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx has  minimum requirements for a server  (web front end, app server, or single server install).

Answer (score 2):

There is no ideal server spec for a SharePoint setup. It all depends on what services you are using, the size of the data, what custommizations are done, how much the users actually are using the farm.

You need to test! Start with the default recommendations from Microsoft and look at their sample architectures: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff601871

It's a quite small installation you're talking about, but... **It depends**.

Personally I would not trust any sizing tools of any kind, they are too generic. Of course you could use those as a starting point.

Comment: As always.... It depends... :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL server will take as much memory as it can, seeing as a database loaded in memory performs best. You should consider at least splitting the sql and sharepoint installations on different machines. We usually go for 4CPU, 8GB RAM and 50GB + 50GB disks on a sharepoint machine.

SQL is usually not used solely for sharepoint, so get is as heavy as budget permits :-D

Comment: If you're sharing SQL (instance) between different applications you're in trouble with different SLA's etc. Get a dedicated SQL server/instance for SharePoint.

Comment: Of course, but that is a bridge to far in this question I think. That's what we do though. And of course use a SQL Alias on your sharepoint machine :-D

Comment: PS, you need to change your name, seeing as you are an MCA as well now :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [HP Sharepoint sizer Tool](http://h71019.www7.hp.com/activeanswers/Secure/548230-0-0-0-121.html).